# Next and previous buttons for a queryset in a DetailView

Tags: django

I'm new to Django, and I'm working on my first real (i.e., non-tutorial) project. I have class-based ListViews on four models, and the lists can be filtered in various ways. The user can click on anything in a filtered list to get a DetailView of the item. This is all straightforward and works fine.

I would like to have Previous and Next buttons on the detail pages that allow the user to step through the current filtered set in the default order (which is not date or id). I've found various bits and pieces on StackOverflow and elsewhere that look like parts of a solution, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make them all work together in my views.

Here is slightly simplified code for one of my tables. "Works" are various items (plays, operas, ballets, etc.) that were performed in one of two theaters.

```
models.py

class Work(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sort_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sort_title']
```

The field `sort_title` strips off articles at the beginnings of titles (which are in German and French) and deals with accented characters and the like, so that the titles will sort correctly alphabetically. This is the order of the filtered sets, and I want to retain that order for the Previous and Next buttons.

```
views.py

class WorkList(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'works'
    model = Work
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'works.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            return Work.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        else:
            return Work.objects.all()

class WorkDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'work'
    model = Work
    template_name = 'work.html'
```

At the moment, the user can only filter Works by title, but I may add the possibility of filtering by genre (hence the `Q`, which I'm already using for other views). I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I would use some version of the following for the buttons on the detail pages:

```
<ul class="pagination pt-3">
  <li class="page-link"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
  <li class="page-link ml-auto"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

But since I don't know how to make this work yet, I don't know what the URLs will be.

I've tried [`django-next-previous`](https://pypi.org/project/django-next-prev/), which works well in the shell, but I can't figure out how to make it work in my views. Since I want to preserve the filtered queryset from the ListView and use it in the DetailView, I've also experimented with this approach to saving the queryset in the session: https://gist.github.com/bsnux/4672788. But I haven't been able to figure out how to use this to pass the queryset between the two views.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: I haven't tried this before but it may work. You can make a detail view class which inherits from your WorkList and paginate it by one. Basically your DetailView would be a list view which shows one item per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The queries

Previous page:

```py
Work.objects.filter(sort_title__lt=self.object.sort_title).reverse().values('id')[:1]
```

Next page:

```py
Work.objects.filter(sort_title__gt=self.object.sort_title).values('id')[:1]
```

Next page if `sort_title` is not unique - note the `gte` rather than `gt`:

```py
Work.objects.filter(sort_title__gte=self.object.sort_title).exclude(id=self.object.id).values('id')[:1]
```

#### Explanation

1. `filter(...)`**:** The `Work` object is ordered by the `sort_title` field by default. So by asking for a `sort_title` that is greater than the `sort_title` of the current object, so we will find the next `Work` object in the set.
2. `self.object` is how we access the current object from a `DetailView`.
3. `values('id')`**:** Only select the values we need to `reverse()` the URL to a different `WorkDetail`. I'm making a presumption that this is the `id` field, but if it's not, it can be substituted with another field.
4. `[:1]`**:** Basically just adds `LIMIT 1` to the SQL query. We only need the next in the set.

This all keeps the queries lightweight.

Note that these queries only work (using `__lt` with `reverse()` for previous page and `__gt` for next page) because the default ordering of the `Work` model is by `sort_title` ascending.

#### Putting it together

Given that your `ListView` and `DetailView` will be sharing the same queryset logic, it might make sense to use a mixin, for example:

```py
class WorkQueryMixin:
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            return Work.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        else:
            return Work.objects.all()
```

The query parameter could be returned in a different way (e.g. through the session data).

Getting it into context, for example for the next page:

```
class WorkDetail(WorkQueryMixin, DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'work'
    model = Work
    template_name = 'work.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        next_id = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(sort_title__gt=self.object.sort_title)
            .values('id')[:1]
        )
        # There may be no next page
        if next_id:
            context['next_id'] = next_id[0]['id']
        return context
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer. I'll see if I can make it work!

Comment: I just realised that the queries should be sorting by `sort_title` rather than `title`. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to make this work now, but haven't succeeded yet. I don't have any experience with mixins. What should the ListView look like if I'm using a mixin?

Comment: You use mixins in the class definition, so for example, `class WorkList(ListView, WorkQueryMixin):` and `class WorkDetail(DetailView, WorkQueryMixin):`

Comment: That's what I guess. But I'm now getting ```Reverse for 'work' with arguments '('',)' not found``` when I click on a link in the Works list.

Comment: How do I set the queryset inside the list view if I'm using the mixin. Sorry, I really am still a beginner!

Comment: You shouldn't need to. The `WorkList` class will inherit the method. Once you add the mixin there should be no difference when you delete the `get_queryset(self)` method. The queryset can be appended to from `WorkList` if needed though using `super()`.

Comment: Two things: (1) the WorkQueryMixin seems to ignore the query; in other words, the ```get_queryset``` works when it's in the list view, but not when I abstract it out to the mixin with the identical code as you did; (2) ```Work.objects.filter(sort_title__lt=self.object.sort_title).values('id')[:1]``` is returning the id of the first item in the queryset, not the one previous to the current item. I haven't figure out the solution to either problem yet. But thanks for your help so far, I'm learning a lot.

Comment: Regarding (2) try my edited version in my answer with the `.reverse()` added

Comment: Problem 1 solved. According to https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/27/django-tip-15-cbv-mixins.html, the mixin name has to go to the left of the view name: ```class WorkList(WorkQueryMixin, ListView):``` That seems to have fixed the fist problem.

Comment: Thanks for (2). I'm testing another solution right now that works in simple cases. If I have trouble with more complex cases, I'll try yours. Thanks again!

Comment: `first()` and `last()` are similar but not exactly the same. They return full objects so the SQL query selects all columns rather than just the `id` column. Functionally the result is similar, they're just bigger queries. Your query is stored in the `?q=` parameter. When you generate last/next URLs you need to ensure those URLs have the same query appended to them. You could use `request.GET.urlencode()`

Comment: How would that work? Where would ```request.GET.urlencode()``` go?

Comment: It's up to you. `urlencode()` regenerates the full query string for the current request e.g. `q=mytitle`. You can call it inside or outside of the template. I can't see your urls.py but something like `<a href="{% url 'work_detail' id=next_id %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">`

Comment: Eureka! That seems to work. I'll have to test it more thoroughly, but it's very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to [elyas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13507148/elyas) for the great detailed initial answer and for taking the time to coach me through the details of the implementation. I now have functional Previous and Next buttons that retain the current queryset. Here is the code I ended up with, including both Previous and Next buttons, with a genre filter added:

```
views.py

class WorkQueryMixin:
    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query is not None:
            return Work.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | 
                  Q(genre__icontains=query))
        else:
            return Work.objects.all()

class WorkList(WorkQueryMixin, ListView):
    context_object_name = 'works'
    model = Work
    paginate_by = 50
    template_name = 'my_app/works.html'

class WorkDetail(WorkQueryMixin, DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'work'
    model = Work
    template_name = 'my_app/work.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        prev_pk = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(sort_title__lt=self.object.sort_title)
            .reverse().values('pk')[:1]
        )
        # There may be no next page
        if prev_pk:
            context['prev_pk'] = prev_pk[0]['pk']
    
        next_pk = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(sort_title__gt=self.object.sort_title)
            .values('pk').values('pk')[:1]
        )
        # There may be no next page
        if next_pk:
            context['next_pk'] = next_pk[0]['pk']
    
        return context
```

In the template for the Works list view, using classes from Bootstrap 4:

```
<ul>
  {% for work in works %}
    <a href="{% url 'my_app:work' work.pk %}?{{ 
      request.GET.urlencode }}" class="list-group-item list-group- 
      item-action">
        {% if work.title == "No title" %}
          {{work.title}}
        {% else %}
          <em>{{work.title}}</em>
        {% endif %} ({{work.genre}})
    </a>
  {% empty %}
    <p>No works match this search</p>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And in the template for the Work detail view:

```
<ul class="pagination pt-3">
  {% if prev_pk %}
    <li class="page-link"><a href="{% url 'my_app:work' prev_pk %}?{{ 
        request.GET.urlencode }}">Previous</a></li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if next_pk %}
    <li class="page-link ml-auto"><a href="{% url 'my_app:work' next_pk 
        %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">Next</a></li>
  {% endif %}
</ul>
```